# how to make the ImageSwitcher run automatically

Tags: android, android-layout

hi am Trying to use ImageSwitcher  i manage to make it work but i have problem is that i need to press start to make it start and stop to make it stop , i want it to start automatically when the activity start

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

{
    private ImageSwitcher imageSwitcher;

```
private int[] gallery = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f};

private int position = 0;

private Timer timer = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageSwitcher = (ImageSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.imageSwitcher);

    imageSwitcher.setFactory(new ViewFactory() {

         public View makeView() 
         {
             return new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
         } 
     });

     // Set animations http://danielme.com/2013/08/18/diseno-android-transiciones-entre-activities/
     Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
     Animation fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_out);
     imageSwitcher.setInAnimation(fadeIn);
     imageSwitcher.setOutAnimation(fadeOut);         
}



//////////////////////BUTTONS

public void start(View button)
{        
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

    public void run() {
        // avoid exception: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views"
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 imageSwitcher.setImageResource(gallery[position]);
                    position++;
                    if (position == 6)
                    {
                        position = 0;
                    }
            }
        });
    }

    }, 0, 2500);

}

public void stop(View button)
{   
    timer.cancel();
}
```

}

Comment: please help me i need it

Answer (score 1):

You just can call on your onCreate the method start(null) (with null parameter) and that's it, if you want it to stop then call the stop method with null parameter when the timer is up.